# Polymerfire - What is the correct way to update firebase values

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, polymer-1.0, firebase-polymer, polymerfire

what is the `correct` way to update a firebase value? is it to use firebase-document? I understand that in polymerfire,  has been deprecated. However, in  https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list, I could simply update the collection like so:

```
<firebase-collection location="{{userLocation}}" data="{{fbTodos}}" 
                     on-firebase-value="_firebaseLoaded">
</firebase-collection>
_firebaseLoaded: function() {
    this._firebaseConnected = true;
    this.todos = this.fbTodos;
    this.backupTodos = this.fbTodos;
    this.linkPaths('fbTodos', 'todos');
    this.linkPaths('backupTodos', 'todos');
    },
```

......

```
deleteTodo: function(e) {
 this.arrayDelete('todos', e.detail.todo);
 },
```

What is the proper way to update firebase db? Btw, what does `this.linkPaths` do? Without `linkPaths`, the firebase db is not updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the reply on this issue https://github.com/firebase/polymerfire/issues/15, it seems  is the way to go.